# In photoshop cs5 the color of my image changes when I enter full screen mode, how do I fix it?

Tags: photoshop, color, color-management, photoshop-cs5

I am working in PScs5 on a EIZO color edge monitor. When I open my image photoshop displays all of the colors fine. When I change to full frame viewing, the image color becomes very muted and washed out. After this happens if I put it back to normal screen the colors stay muted. I can save the image, close it, and when it reopens the color are back to normal, like nothing happened. What is happening?
I am very frustrated. I have calibrated my monitor twice and nothing has changed. I have never come across this before and I am totally stumped.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Did you check your video card recently? What is your video memory?

Comment: Question: Do you have more than one video card (integrated and discrete) and working on a laptop ?

Comment: I working on a tower (MAC OS X 10.7.4) , but I have two monitors (one is a mac and the other is an EIZO,  the issue happens on both monitors. Im  not even sure where to look to see if I have more than one video card.....

Answer (score 2):

There has been some posted issues on this problem for CS5 at this link: http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/colour_glitches_when_switching_to_fullscreen_mode_in_photoshop

An easy test is to turn off OpenGL Drawing in Preferences and see if the problem goes away.  Hope this helps.

Comment: try to explain tye answer rather than simply putting a link :)

Comment: AHHH! THANK YOU! I think this will solve the problem. I will try tomorrow.

Comment: I tried changing my OpenGL Drawing in Preferences from Basic to Normal and my colors no longer shift. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Turning off OpenGL Drawing worked for me as well. Nice to know I don't have to return the monitor.